# orderBy pipe doesn't works properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pipe, ionic4

I'm using ngx-pipes from page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pipes#orderby

i'm using specifically the pipe orderBy, but when i use the orderBy pipe in my HTML, the information doesn't be ordered correctly (in order of minor to major).

I tried putting an extra property in the treated object, this property called diff is the result of the sum of (lat and lng) TREATED PROPERTIES, not the original

and using that property instead of using the lat and lng properties both, but doesn't works...

Here is my home.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <p *ngFor = "let geo of absUserLocations | orderBy: ['lat', 'lng']">
      lat: {{geo.lat}}<br>
      lng: {{geo.lng}}<br>
    </p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and this is my home.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  public myCurrentLocation = {lat: 44.6, lng: 10.50};
  public absUserLocations = [];
  public userGeolocations = [];

  constructor() {

    this.userGeolocations = [
      {
        lat: 44.71620446490455,
        lng: 10.692454582877872
      },
      {
        lat: 44.63622591783756,
        lng: 10.575689162245453
      },
      {
        lat: 44.827688291479625,
        lng: 10.580959962491988
      },
      {
        lat: 44.618612858983525,
        lng: 10.650185180418703
      },
      {
        lat: 44.83988342851342,
        lng: 10.757238916147344
      }
    ];

    this.userGeolocations.forEach((userLocation)=>{

      this.absUserLocations = 
      this.absUserLocations.concat([this.getUsersDistance(userLocation)]);

    });

  }

  toGeoposition(str){let [lat, lng] = [...str.split(";")]; return {lat, lng}}

  getUsersDistance(destinyUserLoc){

    return {
      lat: Math.abs(this.myCurrentLocation.lat - destinyUserLoc.lat), 
      lng: Math.abs(this.myCurrentLocation.lng - destinyUserLoc.lng)
    }

  }

}
```

Note: the reason i have two location array objects and i only iterate on one is that the second array (absUserLocations), will contain the calc of the absolute value between the difference of the user current location and the other users location, with this calc, i'm able to show with the orderBy pipe the nearest users around the user location.

In my real project obviously i'm not going to show geolocations, but i made this short code to confirm that all is in order.

When i see the results in the document, and i calculate the sum of the lat and lng of each object and compare it in order with the others, i realize that the order is wrong!, i simply need to show the information of absUserLocations in order from minor to major...

this is the order that i'm currently getting:

[image]

Comment: And what order does it show in as you have the code at the moment?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: if where ordered correctly, in order of minor to major the results should be ordered as [1, 0, 3, 2, 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderBy pipe is working as expected with the data you've given it, in that it will sort the data in ascending order by lat, then by lng (which practically means by lat because all your lats are different). As you wrote at the beginning of the question, what you really want to order by is the lat diff + the lng diff.

```
<p *ngFor = "let geo of absUserLocations | orderBy: ['diff']">
```

```
this.absUserLocations = this.userGeolocations.map(loc => {
  const latDiff = Math.abs(this.myCurrentLocation.lat - loc.lat);
  const lngDiff = Math.abs(this.myCurrentLocation.lng - loc.lng);
  const diff = latDiff + lngDiff;
  return {lat: latDiff, lng: lngDiff, diff};
});
```

Comment: I don't know why when i made before something like that doesn't works... thanks!, worked as expected :3